# $(180+n)\cdot n$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Hi an old question from the late Edwin Weiss's A First Course in Algebra and Number Theory:

> Find all n such that $n(180+n)$ is a perfect square.

Prof Weiss, who wrote marvelous problems, passed 25 years ago, and his book, which we used in his course in 1979, is long out of print.  But I would be grateful to have an answer here.

Comment: Notice that $n(180+n)=(n+90)^2-90^2$ so $90$ is part of Pythagorean triple. Therefore, list all the $s, t$s such that either $s^2-t^2=90$ or $2st=90$.

Comment: @didgogns.  A pythagorean triplet is of the form $(2stk, (s^2-t^2)k, (s^2+t^2)k).$ For example $(12,9,15).$ Only the primitive triplets require $k=1.$

Answer (score 2):

We have $$n^2+180n=k^2$$ implying $$n^2+180n+8100=k^2+8100$$

Hence $(n+90)^2-k^2=8100$ , hence $(n+90-k)(n+90+k)=8100$

Now determine all integer pairs $(a/b)$ with $ab=8100$ and solve the equation system $$n+90-k=a$$ $$n+90+k=b$$ If this system has a solution in integers, this solution also solves the given equation.

Comment: Note this system has solutions exactly when $a,b$ are both even. We could also limit the search to $a\le b$, this give us the $8$ desired solutions.